# Can a single MIDI track play more then one note at once?

Tags: audio, midi

I am writing my own MIDI parser and everything seems to be going nicely.

I am testing against some of the files I see in the wild. I noticed that a MIDI track never appears to have more then one note on at once (produces more then one tone). Is this by design, can a midi track require more then one note to play at once?

(I am not referring to the number of simultaneous tracks, I am referring to the number of tones in a single track.)

The midi files I have tested look like this:

ON_NOTE71:ON_NOTE75:ON_NOTE79
ON_NOTE71:OFF_NOTE71:ON_NOTE75:OFF_NOTE75:ON_NOTE79:OFF_NOTE79

Can it look like this?

ON_NOTE71:ON_NOTE73:OFF_NOTE73:OFF_NOTE71

How do I detect this alternative structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Playing more than one note at once is known as polyphony. Different MIDI specifications define support for different levels of polyphony.

See http://www.midi.org/techspecs/gm.php

Answer (score 1):

The number of notes that can play at once is a hardware implementation detail. Your software should allow for any number of simultaneous notes to be playing at the same time. I suggest keeping a table of which notes are currently on so that you can send a note off for each one when playback is stopped. Ideally the table should have a count for each note that is increased when a note on happens and decreased when a note off happens. That way if a certain pitch has two note on events pending you can send two note off events. You can't know how the device you're communicating with will handle successive note on events for the same pitch so it's safest to send an equal number of note off events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both controllers and software can produce such events.